# Laravel 4 queue job is not deleting from queue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working in `Laravel v4.2`. I have a queue job which I run in the background this queue job process successfully but not deleted from the queue after success and again call for the second attempt and run due to my job attempt condition validation. But it should be deleted from the queue. because it processes successfully on the first attempt. Below is my code that I code

```
public function moveAndDeletePost($job, $data) {
        Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path() . '/logs/testing/ArchivePost.log');
        try {
            Log::info("=== Archive post queue run===");
            Log::info("dateTime=>" . date('Y-m-d h:m:s A'));
            Log::info($data);
            if ($job->attempts() <= 2 && !empty($data)){
                if(isset($data['post_id']) && !empty($data['post_id'])){
                    $response = PostArchiveProcess::getInstance()->deletePost($data['post_id']);
                    if($response->hasError()){
                        $job->delete();
                        Log::info("(26 Queue)Post Delete Error: ".$response->getError());
                    }else{
                        $job->delete();
                        Log::info("Post Delete Success: ".$response->getResponse());
                    }
                }else{
                    $job->delete();
                    Log::info("=== Post index not found ===");
                }
            }else{
                $job->delete();
                Log::info("=== Queue data not found ===");
            }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $job->delete();
            Utility::store_exception($ex);
            Log::info("Post Delete Queue Exception: ".$ex->getMessage());
            Log::info("Post Data: ".$data);
        }
    }
```